# Почему UI кнопки не работают?

Tags: unity3d

Я повесил на них Event Trigger, указал метод, но ничего не работает. В чем проблема? Никаких ошибок в коде не нашел.

Comment: При добавлении на сцену компонента Canvas автоматически создается в отдельном объекте компонент EventSystem. На Вашей сцене он присутствует?

Comment: мб сначала посмотреть любой гайд на ютубе,а потом сюда идти?

Comment: Да, EventSystem присутствует.

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, скриншот, где будут видны компоненты и их настройки на Кнопке.